# Customizing Slider in QT 5.6 (QML)

Tags: qt, slider, qml

I am trying to customize a standard slider that I am using. I am not trying to do much I just want to increase my track width and change the handle to a rectangle. I looked at the documentation but I am having a trouble understanding it. In order to customize the track the documentation has shown the below code

```
track: Rectangle {
    x: control.leftPadding + (horizontal ? 0 : (control.availableWidth - width) / 2)
    y: control.topPadding + (horizontal ? (control.availableHeight - height) / 2 : 0)
    implicitWidth: horizontal ? 200 : 6
    implicitHeight: horizontal ? 6 : 200
    width: horizontal ? control.availableWidth : implicitWidth
    height: horizontal ? implicitHeight : control.availableHeight
    radius: 3
    border.color: "#353637"
    color: "#ffffff"
    scale: horizontal && control.mirrored ? -1 : 1

    readonly property bool horizontal: control.orientation === Qt.Horizontal   
}
```

what is `control` over here?

I am using Qt5.6 and I am using Qt controls lab.
Can someone just point me in the right direction ?

Comment: The *control* in your code snippet is probably referring to the Control Layout of Control QML Type. You can find some relevant information here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html

Answer (score 0):

In analogy to the `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`-Documentation, `control` is the `id` that is set to the `Slider` itself. So they use it to reference the properties of the `Slider`.

The full example should look something like that:

```
Slider {
    id: control // <--- see the control here
    width: 300
    height: 30

    track: Rectangle {
        x: control.leftPadding + (horizontal ? 0 : (control.availableWidth - width) / 2)
        y: control.topPadding + (horizontal ? (control.availableHeight - height) / 2 : 0)
        implicitWidth: horizontal ? 200 : 6
        implicitHeight: horizontal ? 6 : 200
        width: horizontal ? control.availableWidth : implicitWidth
        height: horizontal ? implicitHeight : control.availableHeight
        radius: 3
        border.color: "#353637"
        color: "#ffffff"
        scale: horizontal && control.mirrored ? -1 : 1

        readonly property bool horizontal: control.orientation === Qt.Horizontal   
    }
}
```

Comment: In their customizing slider section. All I could see was the track section. I think they should provide a better explanation as to what it is. Also do I need to import QtQucik.control to proceed further?

Comment: No, you don't. The Qt.labs.controls is somewhat the playground for the QtQuick.Controls 2.0 that became available I think with Qt5.7. You might consider upgrading to this version or even 5.8 to have the *more final* QtQuick.Controls 2.0. There the name would not be `track` but `background`. But if you are contempt with the `Qt.labs.controls` and don't feel the need to upgrade anytime soon, don't import `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` for those have another slider, which is most likely way worse in performance.

Comment: I feel that making GUI using QML just sucks, everything that I want to do is just a big task or maybe I just suck at it. But I am learning,  thanks for help.